# Laravel templating structure to allow separate folder for templates?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a normal laravel installation which means my blade files are all found at:

```
/laravel/resources/views
```

I want to create another folder, ideally at this location:

```
/templates
```

And have specifically:

```
/templates/myCustomTheme
```

If I have breadcrumb.blade.php located at:

```
/laravel/resources/views/breadcrumb.blade.php
```

And I also have:

```
/templates/myCustomTheme/breadcrumb.blade.php
```

Then I want laravel to instead use the latter myCustomTheme breadcrumb file.

Any ideas on where to start to get this right?

Thanks!

Comment: custom theme name can dynamic or static?

Comment: You can override the default view path in [config/view.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/view.php) but having both is more complicated. For that you should consider reading [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages#views)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package

https://github.com/Shipu/themevel

Since this package supports many features which require to do multitheme support

```
Custom theme path
Override theme
Parent theme support
Unlimited Parent view finding
Asset Finding
Theme translator support
Multiple theme config extension
Multiple theme changelog extension
Artisan console commands
Theme enable only Specific route via middleware
Almost everything customizable
Also Laravel 7.0+, 8.0+ Support
```

For switching current theme you can use set method in service provider or middleware base on your requirements

```
Theme::set('theme-name');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like adding modules when not necessary, and also not if I can somehow have some sort of faith in who is  developing it. I have no idea who is developing this, and for my requirements, I simply needed to add one line of code:

In config/view.php I did this:

```
'paths' => [
   resource_path('themes/myCustomTheme'),
   resource_path('views'),
],
```

Works perfectly!